# CSS Image Layouting before image loaded

Tags: css, image, layout

For my mobile website I want to show images of different but known heights/widths with two constraints:

- The image should take up the whole width of the browserview
- The height should be scaled (down or up) accordingly to keep the proportions

As soon as the browser downloads the image, it is really easy with the following CSS:

```
<img src="myImageURl" style="width: 100%; height: auto;" />
```

But because the loading of the image takes some time, I want the browser to layout the image before it downloads it. So the browser does not need to rerender the page, once he fetches the image. I tried the following approaches, which failed:

```
// The image is not layouted before fetched
<img src="myImageURl" height="myImageHeight" width="myImageWidth" style="width: 100%; height: auto;" /> 

// The image is layouted, but wrong: height is not proportional to the width anymore
<img src="myImageURl" style="width: 100%; height: myImageHeight;" />
```

I would love some help here. But please in CSS, I don't want to use Javascript / jQuery if I don't have to.

**UPDATE**

I guess I am not the only one with this problem: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/3274/fluid-images-how-to-set-width-and-height

Comment: you are unable to do this unless you use some sort of scripting language - the browser doesn't know the size of the image until it has downloaded it so you would need to do a manual calculation if you already know the image size

Comment: Actually the browser DOES know the image size. At least I know the image size before the image is loaded and I tried to "tell" the browser with the height and width attributes of the <img>. But that approach didnt work.

Comment: yeah but you're not telling it the resized height - you're telling it the original height which it will take the space of until it has loaded and the css kicks in

Comment: I am just saying: I can provide all the necessary information to layout the image, before the image is actually fetched from the server. I am asking in this thread if there is a proper way in CSS to tell the browser all these information. If not, it seems to me like a missing feature in CSS, but at least I would know that it is not possible as of now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Image with declared width and height renders square before load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19606983/image-with-declared-width-and-height-renders-square-before-load)

Comment: Well, if there is any duplicate it is the other question. But this answer here is different and of high value, because it has a CSS only solution.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

As Pete already said, you can not do any (automatic) calculations before the image is downloaded, so the browser knows its width and height.

But since you are able to determine the aspect ratio of the image beforehand, you could try a “workaround” by adding an extra placeholder element around the image – and make use of the fact that [`padding` values given in percentage always are calculated based on the **width** of an element, even for padding-top/-bottom](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#padding-properties).

That could look something like this:

```
<div style="position:relative; width:100%; height:0; padding-top:50%;">
  <img style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%;" src="…">
</div>
```

This is a `div` element with no height, but a padding-top – that will give it an actual “height” of 50% of the computed 100% width. (That would be for an image with an aspect ratio of `2:1` – for `3:1` the padding-top value would have to be 33.333% accordingly – and so forth, basically `height/width*100`.)

That should span up our placeholder even before the image is loaded.

The image itself is positioned absolutely inside this relatively positioned placeholder – that makes sure it gets displayed at the same position in the document.

The only thing that *might* be problematic is rounding that has to occur for values with decimal points – 33.333% of 1000 pixels would be 333.33 pixels, and the browser has to round that down to 333 pixels. Should the resized image have an actual height of 334 pixels however, it would just flow out of the area the placeholder div is spanning up by that one pixel. May depend on the actual layout (and your fetish for pixel-perfect accuracy) whether that’s acceptable or not.

Comment: It seems that your solution works really well! I just need to test some things, before I mark it as accepted. Thanks a lot.