# CSS height:auto starting value?

Tags: css

I recently started adding `max-width:100%` and `height:auto` to my images so the browser can shrink them to fit the screen if necessary.  The only downside to this that I've found is each of the "placeholder" spaces where the images will load on the page seems to have a `height` of zero before the images load.  This causes the page elements to jump around after the page loads but before all of the images are loaded.  This makes sense given how `height:auto` works, but I'm wondering if anyone has come up with a creative solution to prevent it.

Comment: What about setting `min-height` to any value? How should the browser know the ratio of your image before it is loaded?

Comment: see a bit of code would be useful

Comment: what is the result if you take off that height:auto?

Comment: **html**
`<div id="container">
<div id="imageHolder"></div>
</div>`
**CSS**
`#container{
height : calc(100%); /*supported in new browsers*/
width:100%;
}
#imageHolder{
background-image: url(image) no-repeat;
background-size: 100% 100%;
}`

You can try his code, correct it as per your requirement. This can be a possible solution. Try it and let me know..

Comment: you can change the **container** height. its child div will occupy accordingly..

Comment: I described a possible solution a while ago here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15520623/css-image-layouting-before-image-loaded/15521298#15521298

Comment: I've actually started to like the way the page is compact before the images have loaded and then spreads out as they load.  I think it's easier to absorb the page's text that way than to stare at a lot of white space.  However I like Nirus's and CBroe's solutions.  Nirus, would that work with an img in place of the imageHolder div?  Do non-new browsers degrade gracefully?

Answer (score 0):

One solution as someone has stated is setting a `min-height`:

```
.placeholder {
    height: auto;
    min-height: 140px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

The issue with this however is that it will still probably bounce around, just from 140px to whatever the size of the image is, and it also means that all the images you have have to be taller than whatever `min-height` you set.

Unfortunately, since your issue is while the page is loading there's little you can do with JavaScript to dynamically load images and set the heights of their placeholders appropriately.

One thing you *could* do is something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Head stuff ... -->
</head>
<body>
    <div id="staggerer" style="display: none;">
        <!-- Put page content inside this ... -->
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        window.onload = function() {
            document.getElementById('staggerer').style.display = "block";
        };

        // Or in jQuery:

        $(window).load( function() {
            $('#staggerer').css('display', 'block');
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This would just wait until *everything* has loaded before displaying the page content. This solution might not be appropriate if you page takes a long time to load, and of course relies on JavaScript.