# Image with declared width and height renders square before load

Tags: html, css, image

I have images with declared widths and heights, e.g.:

```
<img src="foo.jpg" width="1500" height="1800" alt="bar" />
```

They are within a responsive grid, so they display at `max-width: 100%`. They are lazyloaded in. The problem is that despite having `height: auto;`, the images always display square **before** they are loaded, which creates a jump in page height when they have finished loading.

So the above image example, in my 960px width grid, would display a placeholder at 960px x 960px until the full image loads, at which point it will be 960px x Y (where Y is the correct height).

My question is how can I get the placeholder image to mimic the final loaded dimensions of the actual image?

Comment: Can you show the code how your images are loaded?

Comment: Firstly, you have an error: `width` and `height` attributes do not take CSS units. Either change the values to whole numbers only, or use a style attribute. Secondly, are you saying you have `height:auto` in your CSS but `height=(value)` in your HTML? Never do that.

Comment: @MrLister Good catch on the width/height px issue. Re: `height:auto` in the CSS, without it the images stretch to their declared height. This is part of the issue though, because conversely, if I don't declare the `height` within `img`, surely I can't expect to avoid page height jumping around when the images have loaded?

Comment: If the image hasn't loaded, how can you expect to know it's size?

Comment: @bjb568 the "hint" from width/height attributes is supposed to inform the browser like it does in a situation w/o fluid width.

Comment: Oh, so you know the dimensions in advanced?

Comment: @bjb568 yes, they're known. e.g. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vxncu/

Comment: If this image is supposed to be responsive then you should remove width and height in HTML, and use `max-width:100%; height:auto` in your CSS

Comment: it would be better if @cavill could provide the Code so we can play with it.

Comment: @dippas the pen I linked to above is a good example of how to reproduce

Comment: Probably [this](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/3274/fluid-images-how-to-set-width-and-height) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15520623/css-image-layouting-before-image-loaded) helps

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15520623/css-image-layouting-before-image-loaded

Comment: try min-height on image

Comment: Which server-side language are you using?

Comment: Try setting min-height and min-width.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve the desired effect with the following solution.

**HTML:**

```
<img src="blank.gif" class="lazy" data-src="foo.png" width="1500" height="1800" alt="bar">  
             ▲                ▲  
             ║                ╚═══ The class will be used for the lazy loader below  
             ║  
             ╚═══ Use faulty gif here to hide it from showing before loaded
```

> **Hint**:   If you want the placeholder rectangle to be visible and in one color, consider using a 1x1 px image for `blank.gif`. It will load
>   very fast and will stretch nicely to your proportions, filling it with
>   the color of your choosing.

**JavaScript:**

```
/* lazyload.js (c) Lorenzo Giuliani
 * MIT License (http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.html)
 *
 * expects a list of:  
 * `<img src="blank.gif" data-src="my_image.png" width="600" height="400" class="lazy">`
 */

!function(window){
  var $q = function(q, res){
        if (document.querySelectorAll) {
          res = document.querySelectorAll(q);
        } else {
          var d=document
            , a=d.styleSheets[0] || d.createStyleSheet();
          a.addRule(q,'f:b');
          for(var l=d.all,b=0,c=[],f=l.length;b<f;b++)
            l[b].currentStyle.f && c.push(l[b]);

          a.removeRule(0);
          res = c;
        }
        return res;
      }
    , addEventListener = function(evt, fn){
        window.addEventListener
          ? this.addEventListener(evt, fn, false)
          : (window.attachEvent)
            ? this.attachEvent('on' + evt, fn)
            : this['on' + evt] = fn;
      }
    , _has = function(obj, key) {
        return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key);
      }
    ;

  function loadImage (el, fn) {
    var img = new Image()
      , src = el.getAttribute('data-src');
    img.onload = function() {
      if (!! el.parent)
        el.parent.replaceChild(img, el)
      else
        el.src = src;

      fn? fn() : null;
    }
    img.src = src;
  }

  function elementInViewport(el) {
    var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect()

    return (
       rect.top    >= 0
    && rect.left   >= 0
    && rect.top <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight)
    )
  }

    var images = new Array()
      , query = $q('img.lazy')
      , processScroll = function(){
          for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
            if (elementInViewport(images[i])) {
              loadImage(images[i], function () {
                images.splice(i, i);
              });
            }
          };
        }
      ;
    // Array.prototype.slice.call is not callable under our lovely IE8 
    for (var i = 0; i < query.length; i++) {
      images.push(query[i]);
    };

    processScroll();
    addEventListener('scroll',processScroll);

}(this);
```

**Sources:**
The Lazyload script can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/miloplacencia/3931803).

Comment: This is a lazy loading library and doesn't have anything to do with the question being asked.

Comment: It sure does extend it a bit, but it refers to using a dummy src for the img which would resolve the issue of placeholder rectangle being displayed on the screen.

Comment: But we *want* the placeholder to appear on the screen, just in the right aspect ratio, that's all.

Comment: Well, what would you want the placeholder to look? If you just want a rectangle in a single color, you can always use a 1x1px image for `blank.gif`. It will load very fast and will stretch nicely to your proportions, filling it with the color you chose. Is this what you want?

Comment: @bloudermilk: I have updated my answer with this info, and if it works for you you can select it as accepted. If not, we can work other angles.

Answer (score 1):

At time of writing none of the answers explain why this happens or how to overcome it. I found [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15520623/css-image-layouting-before-image-loaded) which is the same as this one that explains an interesting "hack" to get around this.

Answer (score 1):

The following is the only solution that worked 100% of the time, and is much simpler:
https://css-tricks.com/preventing-content-reflow-from-lazy-loaded-images/

In short you can use an SVG placeholder image that contains the dimenions:

```
<img src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 3 2'%3E%3C/svg%3E" data-src="//picsum.photos/900/600" alt="Lazy loading test image" />
```

Here is an React example:

```
const placeholderSrc = (width, height) => `data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 ${width} ${height}"%3E%3C/svg%3E`

const lazyImage = ({url, width, height, alt}) => {
  return (
    <img
      src={placeholderSrc(width, height)}
      data-src={url}
      alt={alt} />
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here i made a **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/v4fct/)** for you

The Main thing is to generate a div around it and setting the height and the width according to what it should be after it loads. then you can load it inside that container and even with a smooth effect ;)

HTML

```
<div class="site-wrapper">
    <div class="lazyload" data-src="http://tinyurl.com/py2nunk" data-width="1920" data-height="1200"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.site-wrapper {
    width:960px;
}
.lazyload {
    max-width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.lazyload img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.lazyload').each(function() {
        var parentwidth = $(this).parent().width();
        var width  = $(this).attr('data-width');    
        var height = $(this).attr('data-height');

        if(parentwidth < width) {
            height = (parentwidth/width*height);
            width = parentwidth;
        }

        $(this).css({ width: width+'px', height: height+'px'});

    });

    // simulating lazyload
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.lazyload').each(function() {
            img = $('<img>', { 'class': 'lazyloaded' }).css({display: 'none'});
            original = $(this);
            $(img).load( function(){
                original.append(img);
                $(this).fadeIn(200);
            }).attr('src', $(this).attr('data-src'));
        });
    }, 5000);
});
```

Let me know if this is what you need or not so i can change according to what you need.

Comment: Is there any way to do this without JavaScript?

Comment: The question isn't asking about lazy loading. The question is specifically asking about keeping image layout proportions before it is loaded.

Comment: Just add `width=""` and `height=""`

Answer (score 0):

Could you please add required max-height for the image in css. I think this would solve your problem.

Comment: Set `max-height` to what?

Answer (score -1):

Right off the bat I notice that you are using px instead of % for width and height. Responsive HTML 5 DOCType. you should use percentage. There to many phones and tablets out there visiting your website.

Use meta tag viewport in your headers. Try something like this

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

For further information on how to correctly re-size your web page for any device go here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

I recon-mind that you use CSS to control the height and width of the image try to stay away from attributes if possible. Use min and max along with your width and height sectors for width and height in you CSS code. You don't need JavaScript to solve your issues

Comment: This does not answer the question.