# Scale height to width when div resizes

Tags: html, css

I have a div with a background image that I would like to scale with the screen width. I'm only interested in this effect for narrow screen widths, and so am using a media query:

```
.the_image{
    margin:50px auto;
    background-image:url('myimage.png');
    background-color:red; /* This is to see the effect */
    background-position:top right;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:608px;
    height:314px;
}


@media (max-width: 708px){
    .the_image{
        width:86%;
        margin:50px 7%;
        background-size: contain;
    }

}
```

This works great to scale the image, except that the height remains the same at 314px regardless of the screen widths. What can I do so that the height scales appropriately (i.e., no red peeking out!)

EDIT:
Here's a jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/mqs9qzvf/. There's no picture, but you can see that the div height doesn't change when the "screen" (viewing pane, in this case) width falls below 708 px.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15520623/css-image-layouting-before-image-loaded/15521298#15521298

Comment: Set the height to auto in the media query, should scale proportionally according to the width. Otherwise it will inherit the height from outside the media query.

Comment: Hi @CBroe, thanks for the link to your other answer, though I am specifically looking for this effect on a div with a background image. (So I can swap in high-res images in the CSS file.)

Comment: @JustinBreiland, thanks for the comment. I tried your suggestion, but it actually makes the whole div disappear when screen width falls below 708px.

Comment: _“though I am specifically looking for this effect on a div with a background image”_ – Doesn’t matter, the basic principle of making the div keep its aspect ratio stays the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the use of JQuery this is quite the tricky thing to do. It would be easy to do would you have a `square` `div` or a rectangle that has a definite ratio like 16:9 or so. There is a method to do this, which requires you to know the exact `%` of the `height` compared to the `width`.

I have made a fiddle for it here: http://jsfiddle.net/3oas7xnp/

This only works for rectangles the size of `608x314`. As you can see the `padding-bottom` expands the `height` of the container `div`. To come up with the `%` number to use here you need to calculate as such:

1. What `%` is `height` of `width`. In this case 314 is what percent of 608.

   314/608 = 51.64
2. What is 51.64% of `width`. In this case the width is 86%.

   0.5164 * 86 = 44.4104%

As you can see this method does work, but isn't more than a workaround. IF by chance all these `divs` will have the same size, feel free to use this method.