# How to pre-populate height of parent div of img?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<div class="main-container">
  <a>
    <img class="img-responsive" />
  </a>
</div>

.container {
  min-width: 300px;
  width: fit-content;
  max-width: 50%;
}

.img-responsive {
   max-width: 100%;
   height: auto;
}
```

This code just works as expected, but as you see on css code, the container's width is 300px initially, and it expands as image is loaded.

Image loading takes time, so main container starts with width=300, height=0.

I would like main container to be expanded already before image is loaded. I have image aspect ratio and width. I want css solution if possible.

For example, if image width is 400px and aspect ratio is 1:1, I would want main-container to be 400x400 to pre-populate img's space before it's loaded.

And when image width is 200px, and aspect ratio is 1:1, the main container should be 300x200.

Answer from [CSS Image Layouting before image loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15520623/css-image-layouting-before-image-loaded) does not help because it always force the width of the container as min width.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS Image Layouting before image loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15520623/css-image-layouting-before-image-loaded)

Comment: It's different from ^. My question has min and max width set on container.

Comment: The answer of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15520623/css-image-layouting-before-image-loaded always force the img size to 300px in my example.

Comment: Then format the `a` as `block`, so that it becomes the containing block the padding percentage is based on.

Comment: It doesn't work. I want it work seamlessly even if the image width is either 200 or 400, which means below or above min-width of container.

Comment: _"I want it work seamlessly"_ - seamlessly _what_? Please give exact examples of how you want this to behave with those different image sizes. (Edit the question please, in comments this gets too messy.) Why for example are you setting a min-width of 300px, and then bring a 200px wide image as example? How do you want it to behave then? Should the image stretch? Be centered? Be specific, instead of just throwing "doesn't work" around.

Comment: _"I would want main-container to be 400x400 to pre-populate img's space before it's loaded"_ - the browser can't guess those 400px image width, so you will have to specify it. That doesn't stop min- or max-width restrictions from applying.

Comment: I have aspect ratio and width of the image prior, but what I don't know is the maximum size of container.

Comment: _"but what I don't know is the maximum size of container"_ - and how is that relevant?

Comment: _"And when image width is 200px, and aspect ratio is 1:1, the main container should be 300x200"_ - if the main problem is that the container would be 300px high, because of the forced 1:1 ratio - then use an additional element (like the `a` you already have there) as the basis for the aspect-ratio-preservation (that'll give you a 200*200px box), and then let that in turn span up the height of the container, that should then be 300*200px due to its min-width constraint.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `min-width` and `min-height` of the either the `div` to the width and height of the image, respectively.

Comment: what value should I set in min-height?

Comment: Whatever you set the `min-height` to will be the height of the container before the image loads. Similarly for `min-width`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-height

Comment: The problem is I don't know what will be min-height. The image size varies.